# Difference between idempotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A_{n\times n}$ and $B_{n\times n}$ are idempotent matrices. How to show that, if $(A-B)^2=A-B$ then $AB=BA=B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are idempotent i.e. $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$ so

$$(A-B)^2=A-B\iff A^2-AB-BA+B^2=A-B\iff AB+BA=2B$$
Now multiply the last equality by $A$ on the left then on the right we get

$$BA=ABA=AB$$
Hence we conclude easily the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! I got it sorted out with your help:
 
 $$AB+BA=2B \Rightarrow AAB+ABA=2AB\Rightarrow AB+ABA=2AB \Rightarrow ABA=AB$$,
 and
 $$AB+BA=2B \Rightarrow ABA+BAA=2BA\Rightarrow ABA+BA=2BA \Rightarrow ABA=BA$$.
 Then:
 $$BA=ABA=AB$$
 $$\Rightarrow AB+BA=2B \Rightarrow AB+AB=2B \Rightarrow 2AB=2B \Rightarrow AB=BA=B.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$
(A-B)A=A^2-BA=A-BA=A(I-B)
$$
so also $(A-B)^2A=(A-B)(A-B)A=(A-B)A(I-B)=A(I-B)^2$.

Therefore, from $(A-B)A=(A-B)^2A$, we get
$$
A-BA=A(I-B)^2
$$
This becomes
$$
A-BA=A-2AB+AB
$$
which yields
$$
BA=AB
$$
Therefore $(A-B)^2=A^2-2AB+B^2=A-2AB+B$ and so
$$
\color{red}{A}-2AB+B=\color{red}{A}-B
$$
Hence $AB=B$.

Comment: Amazing answer great work